# Error while applying function to each row in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, loops

I am trying to apply a function to each line in a file and the end result is applied to only first line in the file. How can I apply below function to each row so that the print statement gives all the rows with applied function

Sample data

```
cvdt35_timestamp_s  gps_lat_dd  gps_lon_dd  coord
03:26.8 42.37659    -83.59011667    [42.3765899995963,-83.5901166667541]
03:27.8 42.37659667 -83.59011667    [42.3765966663758,-83.5901166667541]
03:28.8 42.37660667 -83.59012   [42.3766066670418,-83.5901200001438]
03:33.9 42.376665   -83.59017167    [42.3766650001208,-83.5901716664434]
03:35.9 42.37667167 -83.59020667    [42.3766716669003,-83.5902066667875]
03:36.9 42.37667167 -83.59021667    [42.3766716669003,-83.59021666646]
42:33.6 42.37667167 -83.59021667    [42.3766716669003,-83.59021666646]
42:41.8 42.37667167 -83.59021333    [42.3766716669003,-83.590213333567]
42:53.9 42.37682    -83.58996   [42.3768200000127,-83.5899599999189]
42:59.9 42.37697    -83.58992167    [42.3769700000683,-83.5899216666818]
```

```
import overpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("/home/runner/sample.csv")
df.sort_values(by=['cvdt35_timestamp_s'],inplace=True)

api= overpy.Overpass()
box = 0.0005

with open("sample.csv") as f:
  for row in df.index:
    query = 'way('+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]+box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]+box)+') ["highway"]; (._;>;); out body;'
  print (query)
```

Result I am getting is as below, instead of list of values

way(42.37647,-83.59042167,42.37747,-83.58942167) ["highway"]; (._;>;); out body;

Comment: your print(query) is outside of the loop for which it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Either move your print statement into your loop (see below):

```
with open("sample.csv") as f:
  for row in df.index:
    query = 'way('+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]+box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]+box)+') ["highway"]; (._;>;); out body;'
    print (query)
```

or you can append to a list and then print the list:

```
queries = []
with open("sample.csv") as f:
  for row in df.index:
    query = 'way('+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]+box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]+box)+') ["highway"]; (._;>;); out body;'
    queries.append(query)
print(queries)
```

Comment: @anonymous13 ok great! Do you mind accepting the answer? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration in the for loop you are making the query for that row and the variable query is updated by that value. Here, the query you are prining is the last query. You need to first make a list for the query and append each query to the list. 
This should solve your problem:

```
query = list()
for row in df.index:
        querytemp = query = 'way('+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]+box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]+box)+') ["highway"]; (._;>;); out body;'
        query.append(querytemp)
print (query)
```